# Formal notation for $x=^{+}_{-}a+b$

Tags: notation

We learned in school that the solution $x$ to the equation

$x^2-2x-5=0$ is $x=1\pm\sqrt{6}$.

Now if x is being defined as such, the $\pm$ really means the definition isn't expanded fully; to $x\in\{-\sqrt{6}+1,\sqrt{6}+1\}$[1]. So is this use of $\pm$ really an acceptable way of defining $x$?

I'm thinking no because $|x|=a$ really is the unexpanded version of $x\in\{-a,a\}$ so the same concept should apply

[1]: Is this valid notation?

Comment: It is according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus-minus_sign#In_mathematics).

Comment: Consider using `\pm` ($\pm$) instead of `^{+}_{-}` ($^{+}_{-}$), the spacing and else fits better that way.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the solutions to your equation should be $x=1\pm \sqrt6$

Comment: That's my mistake. You are not missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is proper notation according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus-minus_sign#In_mathematics).

Thanks @Henry W.